# How to ensure that commit contains specific user info in a shared git repository instead of group email id?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-commit, githooks

We have a development server which team members login with a common unix user and work on the same repository. Each team member may clone to different repository and configure the local git user identity with his/her identity and remove the global git user identity. However, regardless of how they do their work, what's the best way to enforce that every commit has the specific user identity instead of the common unix user's identity? I am thinking of using the pre-receive server hook to check for a valid `user.name` and `user.email`. How do I achieve that? I use on-premise GitLab. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just create all account on the server than trying to implement something custom ? Validating the name and the email is a classic feature of git server.

Comment: I can request to change to individual login but how to implement that "something custom" that you mentioned when everyone is sharing the same repository (same folder)?

Comment: I don"t understand `sharing the same repository (same folder)`. Everyone is editing the same files in the same directory, not using a clone of the same repository ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Seems a broken usage, each user should update a local checkout and push it.
The development server should be updated via git action or with a cron

Answer (score 0):

Does GitLab allow you to install your own hooks? If so, you just read up on `pre-receive` hooks and write one something like this. This example is `perl` but you can use `bash` or whatever you like.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
while(<STDIN>)
{
    my ($commit_old, $commit_new, $commit_ref) = ($_ =~ m/^(.*?)\s(.*?)\s(.*)$/);

    open(CHUNKS, "git rev-list --first-parent $commit_old..$commit_new |");
    while(my $commit_chunk = <CHUNKS>)
    {
        chomp $commit_chunk;

        my $cn = `git --no-pager show -s --format='%cn' $commit_chunk`; chomp $cn;
        my $ce = `git --no-pager show -s --format='%ce' $commit_chunk`; chomp $ce;

        my $an = `git --no-pager show -s --format='%an' $commit_chunk`; chomp $an;
        my $ae = `git --no-pager show -s --format='%ae' $commit_chunk`; chomp $ae;

        if (! .. check author name, author email, committer name, committer email however you like against the common identity ...)
        {
            print("Hey you, that's wrong. How many times I have to tell you not to use the common identity?!?!\n;");
            exit 1;
        }
    }
}
exit 0;
```

(For clarity, error checking is removed, as is checking for new branches (with and without commits already in the repo), deleted branches, etc. These are "left as an exercise for the reader", as they say.)